# Is there a way to change formants using parselmouth (python PRAAT wrapper) or other python libraries?

Tags: python, praat

PRAAT provides a way: "Process-> Change formants...", but if I use Parselmouth call:

sound = call(sound0, "Change formants...", f1, f2, f3, f4, 0, 5000)

I get:
"parselmouth.PraatError: Command "Change formants..." not available for given objects."

I really like Parselmouth, but I do wish more examples were available.

Answer (score 0):

Can be using "parselmouth.praat.run_file(path_to_script, parameters)".
Path to script can be obtained from PRAAT's Process->script (in the opened window will be shown path). Doesn't immediately work with some scripts though...
As in case of 'Changeformants.praat' had to comment line20 ("include batch.praat") and then:
sound = parselmouth.praat.run_file(sound0, path_to_script, f1, f2, f3, f4,0,5000, True, False)
did work.

Comment: Further explanation: if I'm not mistaken, "Change formants..." is not included by default in Praat, but part of this "Praat Vocal Toolkit" plugin? Parselmouth indeed doesn't load these plugins, I believe. It's an interesting suggestion to have a way to load plugins, though!

Comment: PS: I would also like more examples in the documentation, but there's always an issue of time :-) Additions are always welcome, though! :-)